# blackberry 10 global tab bar application(global TabbedPane)

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I am creating a application which has a global tab bar ."Actionbar"  should have 5 buttons and should be seen on every screen.
 Is there any way to place 5 tabs on "ActionBar" at one moment without help of "tabbed menu" ?
 And how I can make this tabbed-pane global? because latter in the app I use navigationPane and it replaces tabbedpane.  I want the tabbedPane bar to be visible on all screens

**UPDATE ::::**
   I tried sheets but tabs are dissappearing

```
 import bb.cascades 1.0

TabbedPane {
    showTabsOnActionBar: true
    Tab {

        Page {
            titleBar: TitleBar {
                title: "1"
            }
            attachedObjects: [
                ComponentDefinition {
                    id: mySheet
                    source: "sheets.qml"
                }
            ]
            Button {
                onClicked: {
                    var sheet = mySheet.createObject();
                    sheet.open();
                }
                text: "sheet"
            }
        }
    }
    Tab {
    }
}
```

and my sheets.qml file

import bb.cascades 1.0

```
Sheet {
    id: mySheet
    content: Page {
        Container {
            Label {
                text: "Hi then"
            }
            Button {
                text: "close"
                onClicked: {
                    onClicked: mySheet.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can only have a maximum of 4 tabs visible at a time.  If you have more than 4 then it will have the triple-dot option which brings up the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And how I can make this tabbedpane global? because latter in the app I use navigationPane and it replaces tabbedpane."

If I understand your question correctly, you want there to always be a tabbedpane instead of it being replaced by the navigationpane later.

What you need to to is have your tabbedpane as the main object in your qml.  The navigationpane should be **inside** each tab, so basically 5 tabs means you would have 5 x navigation panes.

When you need to push a page, push it to the relevant tab's navigationpane.

UPDATE:
Sheets allow you to push a page ontop of the tabbedpane.  Here is an example:

Create a qml file with the root item being a sheet, e.g.

```
Sheet {
    content: Page {
        Container {
            ... insert content
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your tabbedpane you would do the following:

inside attachedObjects

```
ComponentDefinition {
    id: sheetDefinition
    source: "mypage.qml"
}
```

in your function/onclick/etc:

```
var sheet = sheetDefinition.createObject;
sheet.open();
```

UPDATE 2:

To push pages within a tabbedpane do something similar to the following:

```
TabbedPane {
    Tab {
        NavigationPane {
            id: tab1Nav
            Page {

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then to push a page use

```
tab1Nav.push(page);
```

Or replace the content of the navigationpane to keep the tabs in place.

Comment: Yeap, but tabbepPane in blackberry by default is present only on the top Page, when i push some other page it dissapears. And also I can't push tabbedPane into tabbedPane

Comment: Aaah, ok what you want is to use sheets then.  Sheets can be placed on top of a tabbedpane without affecting it.  I will update answer and give example.

Comment: I've updated my answer for you.  I misunderstood a bit of what you want to do.  A sheet will go ontop of the entire screen (hiding the tabs) so my original idea is what you need which is that you need to reuse the tabs.  But instead of "push"ing a page, rather replace the contents of the navigationpane.  

Please take note of the order of objects.  Root is the tabbedpane, inside the tab is the navigationpane.  It's the navigationpane you must change, not the tabbedpane and it should work fine.

Comment: after I doing push, tabs are disaaperiang too, I tried it already =(

Comment: "or replace the content of the navigationpane to keep the tabs in place"  => how can I refer tabs from previous page to place them on navigationpane ?

Comment: Best method I found was to use the Qt global variable.  e.g. if you have a navigation pane with id "navPaneTab1" on the tabbedpane oncreationcompleted method you add "Qt.navPaneTab1 = navPaneTab1".  Then in your other pages you can reference any functions or children by calling for example "Qt.navPaneTab1.push(page)"

Comment: thanks, but what i need is this little tabs on the bottom of the screen, I think with current api there is now way to do this.

Comment: One other thing you can try with the page inside a tab is the following:  
tabPageId.removeAll()  //will remove all child elements.
Then you can use a component definition to insert a new page/element/etc.
e.g.
var page = pageComponentDefinition.createObject();
tabPageId.add(page);

That might do what you need.